Найти наибольшую подстроку, являющуюся радугой
Задачка с Т-Поколения
После проливного дождя в Т-стране вышло солнце и небо окрасилось в три цвета:
красный (R),
зеленый (G),
синий (B).
Маленький мальчик Петя успел записать все цвета, которые он увидел, в одну строку s. Но вот незадача: ему стало интересно узнать размер самой большой радуги, которая
была на небе, а считать он умеет только до двух.
Радугой называется строка, имеющая вид R..RG..GB..B. Например, строка RRGGBB является радугой, а RGGBB и GGRRBB - нет.
Помогите Пете! Найдите наибольшую подстроку строки, которую он записал, являющуюся радугой, и выведите её длину. Если ни одна подстрока не является радугой, выведите 0.
Формат входных данных:
В первой строке записано одно целое число n (1 6 n 6 105).
Во второй строке записана строка s состоящая из n символов R, G, B.
Формат выходных данных:
Выведите одно число - длину наибольшей подстроки, являющейся радугой.
Входные данные:
7
RRRGGBB 6
8
RRGGGBBB 0
Языки: C++, Python, Java
Мои попытки:
Python:
Провален тест 2:
def find_rainbow(s):
    max_length = 0
    start = 0  # Позиция первого символа R
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == 'R':
            start = i
            break
    end = len(s) - 1  # Позиция последнего символа B
    while start < end:
        g_pos = start + 1
        while g_pos < end and s[g_pos] != 'G':
            g_pos += 1
        b_pos = end - 1
        while b_pos >= g_pos and s[b_pos] != 'B':
            b_pos -= 1
        if g_pos > start and b_pos < end:  # Радуга найдена
            length = b_pos - start + 1
            if length > max_length:
                max_length = length
        start = g_pos + 1  # Переходим к следующей возможной радуге
    return max_length
n = int(input())
s = input()
result = find_rainbow(s)
print(result)

Провален тест 9:
input()
w=input().upper()
n=w.count('B')
t='R'*n+'G'*n+'B'*n
if t in w:
    print(3*n)
else:
    print(0)

CPP:
Провален тест 1:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
string s1, s2, s3, s4, s5;
int a;
int fin;

int main()
{
    s2 = "RRGGBB";
    s3 = "rrggbb";
    s4 = "rgb";
    s5 = "RGB";
    cin >> a;
    cin >> s1;
    int cnt1 = 0;
    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < s1.length(); ++i)
        if (s1[i] == s2[0])
            if (s1.substr(i, s2.length()) == s2)
            {
                ++cnt1;
                i += s2.length() - 1;
            }
    int cnt2 = 0;
    
    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < s1.length(); ++i)
        if (s1[i] == s3[0])
            if (s1.substr(i, s2.length()) == s2)
            {
                ++cnt2;
                i += s3.length() - 1;
            }
    int cnt3 = 0;

    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < s1.length(); ++i)
        if (s1[i] == s4[0])
            if (s1.substr(i, s2.length()) == s2)
            {
                ++cnt3;
                i += s4.length() - 1;
            }
    int cnt4 = 0;

    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < s1.length(); ++i)
        if (s1[i] == s5[0])
            if (s1.substr(i, s2.length()) == s2)
            {
                ++cnt4;
                i += s5.length() - 1;
            }
    for (int k = 10; k <= 0; k--) {
        if (cnt1 == k || cnt2 == k) {
            fin = 3 * cnt1;
                if (fin <= 0) { fin = 3 * cnt2; }
        }
        if (fin <= 1) {
            if (cnt3 == k || cnt4 == k) {
                fin = 3 * cnt3;
                    if (fin <= 0) { fin = 3 * cnt4; }
            }
        }
    }
    cout << fin;
}

P.S. Помогли в решении на киберфоруме(https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-tasks/thread3178263.html)
Код:
n = int(input())
s = input()
max_cnt = r = g = b = i = 0
while i < n:
    while i < n and s[i] in ['G', 'B']:
        i += 1
    while i < n and s[i] == 'R':
        r += 1
        i += 1
    while i < n and s[i] == 'G' and r:
        g += 1
        i += 1
    while i < n and s[i] == 'B' and r and g:
        b += 1
        i += 1
    if r and g and b and r >= g <= b:
        max_cnt = max(max_cnt, min(r, g, b) * 3)
    r = g = b = 0
print(max_cnt)


Во-первых, определитесь с языком программирования. Во-вторых, учебные задания допустимы только если вы пытались сами его решить, в этом случае добавьте ваши попытки решения.

@insolor исправил. С языком определиться не могу, на каком удобнее будет, на том и пишу

Дело, видимо, не в языке, добавьте тэг алгоритм

На С++ — использовать <regexp> :) Кстати, если имеется URL — то поделиться им обычно помогает получить ответ быстрее и качественнее :) P.S. Если без <regexp> — обычный конечный автомат вам в помощь...

@Harry url - задачка в закрытом контесте

Какие алгоритмы вы  пытались использовать?

считать он умеет только до двух - кто как это понимает?

@MBo, "считать он умеет только до двух" не имеет отношения к задаче. Это мотивация для вовлечения участника: участник помогает маленькому мальчику, который не умеет считать. Вы сами что-то такое почувствовали или нет?

Вот как... А  в радуге, видимо, количество компонентов r,g,b должно быть равным. Как-то нечётко они условия ставят. что-то такое почувствовали - это хорошо было ;)

Спасибо всем за помощь, помогли в решении на другом форуме.

Примерно так с ДКА (без учета непонятного "считать он умеет только до двух" — просто максимальная длина подстроки типа R..RG..GB..B):
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int new_state[4][3] = {{ 1, 0, 0 },{ 1, 2, 0 },{ 1, 2, 3 },{ 1, 0, 3 }};
int act[4][3]       = {{ 1, 0, 0 },{ 2, 2, 0 },{ 1, 2, 2 },{ 1, 0, 2 }};

int rgb(const char * s)
{
    int maxl = 0, count = 0;
    int state = 0;
    for(const char * c = s; *c; c++)
    {
        int in = (toupper(*c) == 'R') ? 0 : (toupper(*c) == 'G') ? 1 : 2;
        if (state == 3 && (in == 0 || in == 1) && maxl < count) maxl = count;
        if (act[state][in] == 2) count++; else count = act[state][in];
        state = new_state[state][in];
    }
    if (state == 3 && maxl < count) maxl = count;
    return maxl;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    cout << rgb(s.c_str()) << endl;
}


Похоже, Вы не учитываете контрпримеры "RGGBB" и
"RRGGGBBB" , которые не является радугами -  видимо, из-за разной длины компонентов

@MBo Естественно. Как я написал, без учета непонятного "считать он умеет только до двух" — просто максимальная длина подстроки типа R..RG..GB..B. Что до разной длины компонентов — то пример RRRGGBB из условия задачи его опровергает.

Не опровергает - есть подстрока RRGGBB

Спасибо всем за помощь, помогли в решении на другом форуме.

@MBo Увы, бессмысленное обсуждение — при отсутствии точной и однозначной формулировки... Будем надеяться, что в следующий раз автор будет не излагать свое видение, а даст точную фомулировку.

Первая программа для примера "RGB" возвращает единицу. Должно быть три.
Вторая программа для примера "RGBB" возращает ноль. Должно быть три.
Третья программа для примера "RGB" возвращает ноль. Должно быть три.
Конечный автомат поддерживает размеры последних групп из R, G, B. Если порядок нарушился, размеры стираются. В радуге должно быть одинаковое количество  всех видов символов. Размер радуги определяется размером группы G. Она должна быть не больше размеров R, B:
input() # skip n
max_g = 0
r = g = b = 0
for c in input():
    if c == 'R':
        if g > 0 or b > 0:
            r = g = b = 0
        r += 1
    if c == 'G':
        if b > 0:
            r = g = b = 0
        g += 1
    if c == 'B':
        b += 1
    if r >= g and b >= g:
        max_g = max(g, max_g)
print(3 * max_g)


Какой - такой? Не понял вас
